# Dynamically create string from pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two data frame like below one is df and another one is anomalies:-

```
d = {'10028': [0], '1058': [25], '20120': [29], '20121': [22],'20122': [0], '20123': [0], '5043': [0], '5046': [0]}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Basically anomalies in a mirror copy of df just in anomalies the value will be 0 or 1 which indicates anomalies where value is 1 and non-anomaly where value is 0

```
d = {'10028': [0], '1058': [1], '20120': [1], '20121': [0],'20122': [0], '20123': [0], '5043': [0], '5046': [0]}

anomalies = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

and I am converting that into a specific format with the below code:-

```
details = (
            '\n' + 'Metric Name' + '\t' + 'Count' + '\t' + 'Anomaly' +
            '\n' + '10028:' + '\t' + str(df.tail(1)['10028'][0]) + '\t' + str(anomalies['10028'][0]) + 
            '\n' + '1058:' + '\t' + '\t' + str(df.tail(1)['1058'][0]) + '\t' + str(anomalies['1058'][0]) + 
            '\n' + '20120:' + '\t' + str(df.tail(1)['20120'][0]) + '\t' + str(anomalies['20120'][0]) + 
            '\n' + '20121:' + '\t' + str(round(df.tail(1)['20121'][0], 2)) + '\t' + str(anomalies['20121'][0]) + 
            '\n' + '20122:' + '\t' + str(round(df.tail(1)['20122'][0], 2)) + '\t' + str(anomalies['20122'][0]) +
            '\n' + '20123:' + '\t' + str(round(df.tail(1)['20123'][0], 3)) + '\t' + str(anomalies['20123'][0]) +
            '\n' + '5043:' + '\t' + str(round(df.tail(1)['5043'][0], 3)) + '\t' + str(anomalies['5043'][0]) +
            '\n' + '5046:' + '\t' + str(round(df.tail(1)['5046'][0], 3)) + '\t' + str(anomalies['5046'][0]) +
            '\n\n' + 'message:' + '\t' +
            'Something wrong with the platform as there is a spike in [values where anomalies == 1].'
                )
```

The problem is the column values are changing always in every run I mean like in this run its `'10028', '1058', '20120', '20121', '20122', '20123', '5043', '5046'` but maybe in next run it will be `'10029', '1038', '20121', '20122', '20123', '5083', '5946'`

How I can create the details dynamically depending on what columns are present in the data frame as I don't want to hard code and in the message i want to pass the name of columns whose value is 1.

The value of columns will always be either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# first part of the string
s = '\n' + 'Metric Name' + '\t' + 'Count' + '\t' + 'Anomaly' 

# dynamically add the data
for idx, val in df.iloc[-1].iteritems():
    s += f'\n{idx}\t{val}\t{anomalies[idx][0]}' 
    # for Python 3.5 and below, use this
    # s += '\n{}\t{}\t{}'.format(idx, val, anomalies[idx][0])
    
# last part
s += ('\n\n' + 'message:' + '\t' +
      'Something wrong with the platform as there is a spike in [values where anomalies == 1].'
     )
```

Comment: it gives me error:-   File "<ipython-input-152-616df6ea1447>", line 6
    s += f'\n{idx}\t{val}\t{anomalies[idx][0]}'
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax      i am using python 3 if that related to any error

Comment: the `f` string format is available from Python `3.6+`. If you use earlier version, you need to change it to conventional format function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Hey @Quang, Any idea how I can include a third data frame in this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66003733/dynamically-create-string-from-three-data-frames